# Benchmarking for variant identification using RNA-seq data

Tags: rna-seq, vcf, variant-calling, variation, benchmarking

I am in need to benchmark the variant identification pipeline which uses RNA seq data alone without any matched-normal. I would like to know the reference dataset (and the pipeline on which the dataset was run) that can I use to compare the pipeline results on my dataset. The reference dataset which I use should be comparable regardless of the dataset specific to certain disease. Thanks all in advance for your responses.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, what is your dataset? What species? What kind of sample? You mention the absence of a matched normal, does that mean your sample is from a tumor? We need to understand what you have in order to help you validate.

Comment: The samples come from human related to diabetic condition